# Water Physics (When you Jump In) UNITY 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2d underwater game and i have my gravity set to 0 when the player is in water and i was wondering how do i mimic it so when the player jumps in the water he wont just get stick to the water as he enters it but actually be given a force in just like when you jump in the pool.

i have no code because im just trying to understand the logic of doing it.

Comment: You could try to keep gravity as is, and just add a vertical force when the player hits the water, say half of gravity for example, to slow the player's fall and mimic buoyancy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep gravity = 0 you could use an OnTriggerEnter2D Event and get the current direction and velocity of your player. When you enter the water and set gravity to 0 you apply this vector to the player.

However because there is no force against the force you applied you will have to do more calculations so the water feels real.

A far easier approach is to not set gravity 0 but apply an additional force in the opposite direction of gravity with the value of gravity. And by increasing or decreasing this force you can increase or decrease "buoyancy" of the player.